# How to select attributes from a list of divs in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 16 divs with the class "box" and each "box" has a different name.

```
The first "box" has name="box1";
the second "box" has name="box2";
the third "box" has name="box3";
and so on.....
```

I want to select these individual names, so I attempted to use the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".box").length; i++) {
  console.log($(".box")[i].attr("name"));
}
```

But my console shows that "$(...)[i].attr is not a function".

When I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".box").length; i++) {
  console.log($(".box").attr("name"));
}
```

I get back 16 lines of "box1", which is only the name for the first "box" div.

What I want instead is "box1, box2, box3, box4, box5..."

What can I do?

Comment: Try $('.box'+i).attr('name')

Comment: Please note that `name` is not a supported attribute on `div` elements, hence making your HTML **invalid**. Use `data-name` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$( ".box" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log($(this).attr("name") );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be jQuery? If not, this could work:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.box')]
  .map(d => d.getAttribute('name'))
  .forEach(name => console.log(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery `eq`

```
for (var i = 0; i < $(".box").length; i++) {
  console.log($(".box").eq(i).attr("name"));
}
```

or using fully jQuery version

```
$('.box').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `name` is not a supported attribute on `div` elements, hence making your HTML **invalid**. Use `data-name` instead. Once you changed that, that also makes the code easier:

```
$(".box")[i]
```

gives you the native DOM element in the jQuery collection, which does not have any jQuery methods like `attr()`. It does, tho, have the native DOMElement `dataset` API, so you can simply go with

```
$(".box")[i].getAttribute('data-name')
```

or, even simpler

```
$(".box")[i].dataset.name
```

If you insist on using jQuery **and** also on using an index-based `for`-loop (which I haven't used in years now), go with jQuery's `eq(index)` function:

```
$(".box").eq(i).data("name")
```

As with almost everything, jQuery is just unnecessary bloat you don't need any longer in 2020. Here's the modern way to achieve your goal:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.box')
  .forEach(el => console.log(el.dataset.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

var query_elements = $("#your-div [name]");